# at/in/on summer break

Tags: collocations

You know there are some breaks when students don't go to school for a while like Thanksgiving break, summer break, spring break, winter break, etc.

My questions are

1. what preposition is used before these breaks. What is the right collocation?

We had fun at/on/in summer break.

2. Do all breaks take the same preposition? I'm not sure if e.g.  Thanksgiving break needs specifically 'on' or not.

Thanks

Comment: You can look through these results and see how some of the examples are used: http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=45482623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Students say *on* break to convey that they are not attending school for a period of time:

> I am currently *on* Christmas break.

When talking about the future and what someone is going to do on a school break, we often use *for*:

> I am going to Florida *for* Christmas break. What about you, David?

To talk about a break from school in the past, we often use "over":

> So, James, what did you do *over* Christmas break?

In addition, *during* can be used for the last two cases:

> I am going to Florida *during* Christmas break. What about you, David?
>
> So, James, what did you do *during* Christmas break?

Although it is not a preposition in this case, note that you can use *off* in a number of cases:

> I have this week *off* for Christmas break. (Talking about the present)
>
> I have next week *off* for Christmas break. (Talking about the future)
>
> I had last week *off* for Christmas break. (Talking about the past)

Comment: Your answer isn't incorrect, but I think _at_ can be used, too, especially if it's generally understood that the students have traveled somewhere.